# Linear algebra for javascript

Tags: javascript, php, matlab

I am doing a couple of heavy linear algebra computations in my javascript code which results in blocking the browser. I was wondering what is the best way to handle heavy mathematical computations in a web application?

I am using php on serverside. My question is should I use linear algebra libraries in php or is there a way I can use MATLAB in my web application? Any other suggestions to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use web workers, it like running your code in a seprate thread
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Comment: web workers prevents blocking the browser but the computation still takes long. I would prefer using computational power of server.

Comment: what sort of computation are you doing ??

Comment: I run an animated visualization and I solve a rather large linear system in every animation frame.

Comment: Ok, I tried web workers and it kind of solved my problem. Thank you!